# How to run node.js process with forever and logging?

Tags: node.js, sockets, logging

I see here http://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging/ that if I want to run logs, I do like this:

```
DEBUG=* node yourfile.js
```

this works.

But I want to also run process with forever.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

But now actually I do not even know if I need forever. Then intention of running forever was - if server dies - forever restarts it.

But the problem is that server dies, clients cannot connect and forever does not restart it. Then node process is using socket.io.

So as I understand - process is not dead, but there is something wrong inside the process - with socket.io.

After we restart node server file, it is working again, for about 2 weeks.

As far as I remember - I need forever to run node process in the background. Otherwise process will be stopped when I close terminal.

**How do I run command**

```
DEBUG=* node yourfile.js
```

with forever so it would log output to files?

I tried like this

```
$ forever -c 'DEBUG=* node' server.js
```

but it did not work.

Also tried like this:

```
forever -o out.log -e err.log my-script.js
```

But also did not work, it looks different.

Running like this:

```
forever -o out.log -e err.log start my-script.js
```

starts proccess, but when I run

```
forever logs
```

I do not see any logs, so its no the same.

```
DEBUG=* node yourfile.js
```

floods many logs instantly. I am not sure if I want that much logs, but I have no idea how to solve disconnection problem.

**Update**

Based on comments I tried like this:

DEBUG=* forever start server.js > node.log

node.log file was created, but it just has 3 lines, which means it is not the same log as is when I run

DEBUG=* node server.js

This is what the logs look like which I want to see in text files.

```
socket.io:server initializing namespace / +0ms
  socket.io:server creating engine.io instance with opts {"path":"/socket.io"} +                                                                                            5ms
  socket.io:server attaching client serving req handler +3ms
```

Comment: It's really simple. First do `export DEBUG=*` and then `forever start server.js`

Comment: You can also do `DEBUG=* forever start server.js` or `DEBUG=* forever server.js`. The `DEBUG` you are defining is basically an environment variable. You can access it in node with `process.env.DEBUG`

Comment: That does not log what I expect. As I understand both those comments are about same thing, so did not try what is in first comment.

Comment: Actually looks like doing like your first comment does log. It looked that its the same as doing in 2nd comment, so I expected it to not work. To stop logging - we run "unset DEBUG" and restart node server, right?