# How to run node.js process with forever logging on ubuntu reboot?

Tags: node.js, logging, reboot

There was a topic how to run process with forever and logging.
[How to run node.js process with forever and logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849480/how-to-run-node-js-process-with-forever-and-logging)

How to do this in crontab?

Currently I have this in crontab:

```
@reboot . $HOME/.bashrc
@reboot forever start /path/my_server.js
```

And in my home directory .bashrc there is a line

```
export DEBUG=*
```

Node server starts. But it does not make logs as if I would start manually.
How to fix that?

**Update:**

Cron is for the same user as if I started manually.

Comment: Is the cron for the same user as if you started it manually?

Comment: @Jite - yes, it is for same user

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `source $HOME/.bashrc`

Edit:
You can use https://github.com/chovy/node-startup which it is a boilerplate for an init script, just change few things there and copy to init.d and then with the command `update-rc.d node-app defaults` the process will start whenver you reboot, no need for cron.

you find the manual in the repository. very easy

Comment: Like this: @reboot source $HOME/.bashrc ? Does not help